# IIS 7.5 - Not listening 0.0.0.0:80

Tags: iis, ip, iis-7.5, port, listen

I am using IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2.
From this server, I can access the localhost (standard IIS start page is displayed).
But I can't access it from any other machine belonging to the same network.

I have the impression that the problem is that my server is not listening at the address 0.0.0.0:80.

Because when I do a **netstat -aon | findstr 80** I get only:

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:80           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4

  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
```

But if I do **netsh http show iplisten** I then see (I have added the two last ones manually)

```
IP addresses present in the IP listen list:
-------------------------------------------
    127.0.0.1
    0.0.0.0
    ::
```

One additional test that I did:
When I try **netcat -v xx.xxx.xx.xx 80** on the client, I get the error "Connection refused".
But after doing **netcat -l -p 80** on the server, the netcat connection from client works and I can exchange data.
Because of this I don't think that it is a firewall issue.

Do you have any idea on the causes and how to solve the issue?

Thanks a lot in advance for your feedback!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Question might be better suited for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: OK I will ask it there! Thanks